# confusion regarding fragments' lifeCycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, activity-lifecycle

I have a mainActivity that hosts a ViewPager and contains three Tabs (MQTT, ECO, Logger). the mainActivity has the lifecycles callbacks (onCreat, onResume) and the other three tabs has the Fragment' 
lifeCycle callback (onattached, onCreateView, onViewcreated, onResume, onPause).

at run time, i receive in logCat the following :

```
01-29 13:28:28.732: W/MainActivity(31412): @onCreate().
01-29 13:28:28.802: W/MainActivity(31412): @onResume().
01-29 13:28:28.842: W/MQTT_Settings_Frag(31412): @onAttach().
01-29 13:28:28.842: W/MQTT_Settings_Frag(31412): @onCreateView().
01-29 13:28:28.862: W/MQTT_Settings_Frag(31412): @onViewCreated().
01-29 13:28:28.862: W/MQTT_Settings_Frag(31412): @onResume().
01-29 13:28:28.862: W/Eco_Settings_Frag(31412): @onAttach().
01-29 13:28:28.862: W/Eco_Settings_Frag(31412): @onCreateView().
01-29 13:28:28.892: W/Eco_Settings_Frag(31412): @onViewCreated().
01-29 13:28:28.892: W/Eco_Settings_Frag(31412): @onResume().
```

and when i swipe to go to the Eco-tab "the second one", logCa reports nothing abut the fragments, but when i swipe to the third tab "Logger"-which has been 
implemented yet- logCat displays:

```
01-29 13:37:27.062: W/MQTT_Settings_Frag(31412): @onPause().
```

and when i swipe back from Logger-tab to Eco-Tab, LogCat dispays the following:

```
01-29 13:37:52.292: W/MQTT_Settings_Frag(31412): @onCreateView().
01-29 13:37:52.322: W/MQTT_Settings_Frag(31412): @onViewCreated().
01-29 13:37:52.322: W/MQTT_Settings_Frag(31412): @onResume().


why the first tab "MQTT-Tab" goes in onPause() when i goto only to the third Tab Logger-Tab?
And why the first tab "MQTT-Tab" goes into (onCreateView, onViewCreated, onResume) when i move to the secondtab Eco-tab frm the third one LoggerTab?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewPager only keeps neighbouring tabs on memory by default, thus your first tab is destroyed when you go to your third tab and re-created when you go back to the middle. You can change this behaviour by using `yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int)`.

Comment: does neighbouring tabs mean the three tabs i hosted by the viewpager?

Comment: By neighboring I mean the currently selected/visible one and the ones before and after. It always takes the current view into consideration in these cases.